# Office Add-In for Outlook not sideloading on the app

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, officedev

I have created an custom outlook add in. When I side load it on using the website it works with no issues. When I go into the Outlook app and try to side load, it will install but not show up on the task pane. Is there a reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you see in Outlook? A screenshot can be helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify a few things, when you said using the website is that Outlook on the Web? And when you say the Outlook App, is that Win32 Outlook or Mac Outlook? When you referred to the addin not showing up on taskpane did you mean it's not showing up on the Ribbon? Or it's showing up on the ribbon but the taskpane doesn't show after clicking on the addin in the Ribbon?

Comment: Yes, Outlook on the web. Win32 Outlook.

Comment: It is not showing up in the Ribbon or the taskpane.

Comment: What is your version of Outlook? Can you provide us with your manifest? (Remove any sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why your add-ins may not be displayed in Office applications/task panes. One of them is the use of `http` protocol instead of `https`.

Another point is the privacy control setting in the registry that can be distributed by group policies. Especially the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\privacy -> controllerconnectedservicesenabled
```

if it is set to dword:00000002 (which is disabled).

You need to change it to dword:00000001 (enabled) and the add-in may immediately appear.The relevant information can be found in the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/privacy/manage-privacy-controls).

But I'd suggest starting from the [Troubleshoot development errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors) article.